# SO react-router-bootstrap active link not working properly

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-router, react-bootstrap, react-router-bootstrap

I have a problem with active link using **react-router-bootstrap** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-bootstrap) components. When I navigate to *About*, **active** class appears not only on *About* but in *Home* too.

[Active Link react-router's issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CXWu.png)

This my **Nav** component from **react-bootstrap** (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/):

***NavLinks.jsx***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

import HashNavItem from '../../Navigation/HashNavItem';

// import Flags from './Flags/Flags'
import "./NavLinks.css";

const routes = [{
  name: 'Home',
  path: '/',
  external: false
},{
  name: 'About',
  path: '/about',
  external: false
}, {
  name: 'Stores',
  path: '/#stores',
  external: false
}, {
  name: 'My Account',
  path: 'http://my-react.appicar.com/',
  external: true
}, {
  name: 'Services',
  path: '/#services',
  external: false
}, {
  name: 'Reviews',
  path: '/#reviews',
  external: false
}, {
  name: 'Contact',
  path: '/#contact',
  external: false
}];

export default class MainNav extends Component {

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hola');
  }
  render() {
    let template;

    return (
      <Nav>
        {
          routes.map((route, key) => {
            if (route.external) {
              template = (
                <NavItem eventKey={ 'nav-' + key } href={ route.path } key={ key }>
                  {route.name}
                </NavItem>
              );
            } else {
              template = <HashNavItem eventKey={ 'nav-' + key } name={ route.name } to={ route.path } key={ key } />;
            }
            return template;
          })
        }
      </Nav>
    );
  }
}
```

***HashNavItem.jsx***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";

export default class HashNavItem extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Atributes.
    this.hashFragment = '';
    this.observer = null;
    this.asyncTimerId = null;
    this.scrollFunction = null;
    // States.
    this.state = {
      key: props.eventKey,
      name: props.name,
      to: props.to
    }
    // Methods.
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
    this.getElAndScroll = this.getElAndScroll.bind(this);
    this.hashLinkScroll = this.hashLinkScroll.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  reset() {
    this.hashFragment = '';
    if (this.observer !== null) this.observer.disconnect();
    if (this.asyncTimerId !== null) {
      window.clearTimeout(this.asyncTimerId);
      this.asyncTimerId = null;
    }
  }

  getElAndScroll() {
    const element = document.getElementById(this.hashFragment);
    if (element !== null) {
      this.scrollFunction(element);
      this.reset();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  hashLinkScroll() {
    // Push onto callback queue so it runs after the DOM is updated
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.getElAndScroll() === false) {
        if (this.observer === null) {
          this.observer = new MutationObserver(this.getElAndScroll);
        }
        this.observer.observe(document, {
          attributes: true,
          childList: true,
          subtree: true,
        });
        // if the element doesn't show up in 10 seconds, stop checking
        this.asyncTimerId = window.setTimeout(() => {
          this.reset();
        }, 10000);
      }
    }, 0);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.reset();
    if (this.props.onClick) this.props.onClick(e);
    if (typeof this.props.to === 'string') {
      this.hashFragment = this.props.to
        .split('#')
        .slice(1)
        .join('#');
    } else if (
      typeof this.props.to === 'object' &&
      typeof this.props.to.hash === 'string'
    ) {
      this.hashFragment = this.props.to.hash.replace('#', '');
    }
    if (this.hashFragment !== '') {
      this.scrollFunction =
        this.props.scroll || (el =>
          el.scrollIntoView(this.props.smooth ? { behavior: 'smooth' } : undefined)
        );
      this.hashLinkScroll();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <LinkContainer to={ this.state.to }>
        <NavItem eventKey={ this.state.key } key={ this.state.key } onClick={ this.handleClick }>{ this.state.name } </NavItem>
      </LinkContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

***App.jsx***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

import MainNav from './MainNav/MainNav';
import Logo from './Logo/Logo';
import Footer from './Footer/Footer';
import Copyright from './Copyright/Copyright';
import HomePage from './HomePage/HomePage';
import AboutPage from './AboutPage/AboutPage';
import Error404 from './Error404/Error404';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={ createBrowserHistory() }>
        <div>
          <MainNav />
          <Logo />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={ HomePage } />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={ AboutPage } />
            <Route exact path="/404" component={ Error404 } />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
          <Copyright />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Does anyone knows why ***Home*** is always marked as **active**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **IndexLinkContainer** instead of **LinkContainer**

[Check here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap/issues/193)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will try that, I hope it works! :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you already use [`react-bootstrap`](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/) package, then you can fix your issue like this:

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
    
<Nav>
    <Nav.Link as={NavLink} exact to="/">
        Home
    </Nav.Link>
    <Nav.Link as={NavLink} exact to="/about">
        About
    </Nav.Link>
</Nav>
```

The key here is to use the `exact` property with the `Nav.Link` component and also to set the `as` property to `NavLink` as shown in the above snippet.

[Check the documentation of the `NavLink`'s `exact` property](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md#exact-bool) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with your routes (so react-router not necessarily react-router-bootstrap). I see you put 'exact' in your route declaration but I would try also adding 'strict' to your declaration. In an app I am working on I had to do this in order to get my high-order component validation wrapper to work correctly.

If that doesn't work then my guess would be how you are iterating through the routes array to dynamically create the nav-links. Possibly there is an issue with the package clearing the active state by the way you constructed the nav-links. I am sorry that I don't have a more specific answer! I have yet to get a reputation of 50+ to just be able to leave a comment so a hopefully helpful answer will have to do.